# Question about $P^{-1}AP=B$ equation

Tags: matrices

$P^{-1}AP=\pmatrix{1&-\tfrac{1}{a}\\-\tfrac{1+a^2}{ab}&0}^{-1}\pmatrix{a&b\\-\tfrac{1+a^2}{b}&-a}\pmatrix{1&-\tfrac{1}{a}\\-\tfrac{1+a^2}{ab}&0}=\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}$

This statement is true. How would I find P if I would know only A and $\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}$?
I need an easy way.

Comes from this [Proving that every $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ with $A^2 = -I$ is similar to a given matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382170/proving-that-every-2-times-2-matrix-a-with-a2-i-is-similar-to-a-given).

Comment: I think you might be reading this incorrectly. The product of the three matrices on the LHS are equal to the RHS $\forall a, b$. In fact, the matrix on the RHS is a $90 \deg$ rotation matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the most elementary way possible, but (arguably) not the easiest.

Let $P=\begin{pmatrix} x &y\\ z & w\end{pmatrix}$.

Then $P^{-1}AP=B\iff A\begin{pmatrix} x &y\\ z & w\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} x &y\\ z & w\end{pmatrix}B$.

Now you just need to solve a linear system.

Comment: Is there a faster method to get P?

Comment: @David i thought I saw a faster way. But I don't anymore.

Answer (score 1):

May be this helps: the inverse of $P := \begin{pmatrix} u & x \\ v & y\end{pmatrix}$ is (if $\det(P) \neq 0$):

$$ P^{-1} = \frac{1}{uy-xv} \begin{pmatrix} y & -x \\ -v & u\end{pmatrix}$$.

Then multiply $P^{-1}AP$ and compare it element-wise with the given matrix on the right hand side of your equation. This yields a linear system of equations.

Comment: I've just seen the post of Git Gud, which is probably easier than mine as you don't have the fraction.

Comment: @GitGud You're right - thx!